# How to make a cooldown for a specific user for all commands (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

A user is spamming my commands, how do I make it so all command has the same cooldown for that specific user?

Here is my current code

```
if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id)) {
            msg.channel.send("Wait before getting typing this again. - " + msg.author);
    } else {

           message
channel.send('Cooldown over')

        
        talkedRecently.add(msg.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          
          talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id);
        }, 6000);
    }
```

It wont work because only 1 command and I want the cool down for all commamnds for that specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to execute when a user runs a command such as:

```js
var usersOnCooldown = {};

function setCooldown(userId){
    usersOnCooldown[userId] = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        usersOnCooldown[userId] = false;
    }, 5000);
}

function checkUserCooldown(userId){
    return !(userId in usersOnCooldown) || !usersOnCooldown[userId];
}
```

You could call `setCooldown()` after every command. And `checkUserCooldown()` before every command.